# How to prep a #5 plastic container for making yogurt?

Tags: yogurt

I made a batch of yogurt that went poorly. I use a Salton yogurt machine which uses a #5 plastic bucket. If this were beer, the recipe would call for baking the container to ensure that all the past microbes are dead. Obviously that won't work for a #5 plastic bucket.

It's already been through a dishwashing machine, **so hot water and soap have been covered**.

What other means are there for ensuring that the bacteria from the last batch don't show up in the next batch?

Comment: My family has been making yogurt forever without care for any hygiene standards. Under normal conditions, yogurt cultures have no trouble outcompeting anything when placed in warm milk. I doubt that your problem had to do with container contamination.

Comment: I never baked a container when I was brewing beer, I found a chlorine solution worked very well for sanitizing, although there's other things you could use as well.

Answer (score 2):

For yougurt making, I would say you've covered it.  Someone should correct me if I am wrong, but I would be surprised if anything that would impact the next batch of yogurt survived the dishwasher.

If you want to be certain, though, how about a bleach solution?  Ratios of bleach to water vary widely on the web from 1 tablespoon to 3/4 cup of regular bleach per gallon of water, depending on what you are disinfecting and why. I would think that for this application you could use the lower amounts of bleach.  Soak for a few minutes.  Wash with soap and water.

You referenced beer making:  Beer making suppliers also sell iodine and non-iodine based sanitizers.